# Understanding casting in C++

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion

I came from Java, so when need to call a function like this:

```
struct A {
    int a;
    A(int a) : a(a){ }
};

A foo(A a){
    return A(a);
}
```

I tend to write something like

```
A a = foo(A(10));
```

and it works perfectly fine. But I learnt that it can also be done in this way::

```
A a = foo(static_cast<A>(10));
```

I.e. it enforces the implicit conversion. So, as a rule of thumb should we alsways use `static_cast`-style when we need to exploit implicit conversion? Or there are some cases where function/C-style casts may be necessary?

Comment: You can also write `A a = foo(10);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should static\_cast, dynamic\_cast, const\_cast and reinterpret\_cast be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used)

Comment: @zenith Of course, in this case I can. But it often happens that a constructor is `explicit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two separate aspects worth (re)consideration here: should `A::A(int)` be left implicit, and how best to construct an `A` to pass to `foo`.

For the former, there's no way of deciding without knowing the usage `A` should support, but it's generally recommended to err on the side of having explicit constructors if unsure.

For construction, use `A(10)`  (with C++11, `A{10}` works too), or just `10` to rely on the implicit conversion.  Note that `A(10)` is a constructor call not a cast: there's no need to consider `static_cast<>()` as a preferred casting notation.  The old C-style cast notation is actually `(T)
cast-expression`, per 5.4 [expr.cast] in the C++ Standard.

Answer (score 3):

You never need C-style casts in C++.  As for your examples, the most common way to write it would be this one:

```
A a = foo(A(10));
```

Answer (score 2):

When you want to do a conversion from type `A` to `B`, you have two syntaxes to define the conversion:

```
class B
{
public:
    B(A); # Conversion constructor.
};
```

or

```
class A
{
public:
    operator B(); # Conversion operator.
};
```

For a case like:

```
void f(B b);

int main()
{
   A a;
   f(a);
}
```

If the first version exists, it creates a temporary object of class `B`, using `a` as parameter. If the second version exists (and you implement it, of course), it calls the `operator B()` of class `A` to create an object of type `B` from `a`. If both exists, the compiler throws you a message of ambiguity error.

About down/up-casting, implicit conversions allow upcasting (if source and target types are references/pointers), even if the target base is an innacesible (private) base class of the source. Implicit conversions also allow conversion from a non-const source type to a const target type, or also conversion from rvalue to lvalue and so on.

These are, in short, the rules of implicit conversions. A more complete guide (considering built-in versus user-defined types and built-in conversions) is [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast).

If you use the C++-casting:

```
f(static_cast<B>(a));
```

its nearly the same but with some differences: if `B` is an innaccesible (private) base of `a`, the cast isn't allowed. The other difference is that downcasting is allowed without runtime check (if `B` is a derived class of `A` it allows the casting, even if `a` isn't actually an object of type `B`). That is allowed because runtime check is slow, so, if you KNOW `a` is actually of type `B`, you can safely apply the casting without runtime check.

Other castings are:

```
const_cast<B>(a)
```

Only to change from const to non-const and viceversa.

```
reinterpret_cast<B>(a);
```

Cast everything. Nearly no rules involved. If a conversion from `a` to `B` doesn't exists, it just takes the memory region of `a` and returns it as an object of type `B`. Its the fastest cast alive.

```
dynamic_cast<B>(a);
```

Downcasting with runtime check (both types must be references or pointers). If the real type of `a` isn't `B` (not even a base class of the real type of `a`), an exception or null pointer is thrown/returned (according to if `a` or `B` are references or pointers).

Lastly, the C-casting:

```
f((B)a);
```

What the C-casting does is to try different castings (except `dynamic_cast`, and also allowing casting to innacesible base classes) and use the first which works. I would say the C-casting is as powerful as the implicit cast.

The explicit casting with syntax of funcion call:

```
f(B(a));
```

is equivalent to the C-casting in behaviour.